# How can I use projen Typescript-app generated files?

Tags: aws-cdk

I'm new to CDK so that's the reason I don't get it completely.

With [Projen](https://github.com/projen/projen) which is A new generation of project generators I can create a typescript-app project.

Are this generated files just a construct or actual project? How to for example add an express server to them? or I should use this generated files to generate actual project(s)?

When generating next-js with Projen, at least I see `npx projen dev`  which lets me run it but for typescript-app, I don't see anything to run, just tests pass and not sure what should I do here.

[image]

Comment: I have never used Projen. Can you show what files and folders are gnerated?

Comment: @TrygviLaksafoss I've added a picture to the question